# Change the JuiAsset theme in yii2

Tags: php, oop, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have using the datePicker from yii2-jui and I want to change the Jquery Ui theme used.
I tried harded coded change in `myapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-jui\JuiAsset.php`

```
class JuiAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/jquery-ui';
    public $js = [
        'jquery-ui.js',
    ];
    public $css = [
        'themes/THE_OTHER_THEME/jquery-ui.css',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

Here are a snippet of the `_form` view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Profile */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
...
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'birthdate')->widget(DatePicker::className(), ['clientOptions' => ['dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd']]) ?>
```

However, this way is not [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) solution to get what I want. I don't able to know what I have to do in my view `_form.php` to make it able to override the JuiAsset object's property `$css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only that is not OOP but modifying core Yii files is bad.

2 options:

1. do this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6170 this is the second link that comes when you search on google. If you put the exact name of the question it is number 4 so you may try that in the future
2. Register you new theme (css file) after the one
   registered by default. The classes in the theme registered last will
   overwrite the ones that are default.

**EDIT:**
You told me you are looking for something in the comments

```
  Yii::$app->set('assetManager' , [
                'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
                'bundles' => [
                    'yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset' => [
                        'js' => [],
                        'depends' => [
                            'yii\adminUi\assetsBundle\AdminUiActiveForm',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'yii\grid\GridViewAsset' => [
                        'depends'   => [
                            'backend\assets\AppAsset'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'linkAssets' => true,
            ]);
```

Comment: The second option is not good, because it will lead to unnecessary loading files and longer response (very bad in production). The first is good, but I don't know where and how could I implement it.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html again try google, it is good.

Comment: I already searched it in Yii api, but I tried to change it from the view itself like `Yii::$app->assetManager = ['bundles' => ['yii\jui\JuiAsset' => ['css' =>['themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css',]],],];` but it returned a read only error. However, applying it in the configuration solve it. Now I will search for a way that allow writing configurations values from the view. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

a bit old, but you should put the assetManager override in your config/web.php file under 'components' like so:

```
$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],

'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\jui\JuiAsset' => [
                'css' => [
                    'themes/flick/jquery-ui.css',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],   
],];
```

i just tested this as i was looking for something simmilar, worked just fine